Listing all declared advanced query rewrites in Oracle
The DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE documentation page for Oracle explains how to declare query rewrites and drop them, but doesn't explain how you can list all declared rewrites in the database.
Is it possible to list all of the declared rewrites?

select * from DBA_REWRITE_EQUIVALENCES?

@AndyDBAnalyst Yes, that works! Please rewrite your comment as an answer so I can accept it

select * from DBA_REWRITE_EQUIVALENCES

Reference
